# pull-back connection

Tags: connections

I have a question related to the definition of the pull-back connection, more specifically about its  uniqueness or the canonical way to induce it.

The definition that one finds in general goes along the following lines: let $F:P\rightarrow B$ be map between differentiable manifolds, let $\pi:E\rightarrow B$ be a vector bundle and $\nabla$ a connection on $E$. Then the connection $F^*\nabla$ is uniquely determined by the following relation

$(F^*\nabla)_X(F^* s):=F^*(\nabla_{df(X)} s)$.

This should uniquely determine the connection right?

Let us start with the most trivial case, when $B$ is a point. Then $E$ is a vector space and the pull-back of $E$ is a trivial vector space over $P$. A connection on $E\rightarrow pt$ is an endomorphism of $E$ (which trivially satisfies the Leibniz relation). Could anybody explain how does that canonically induce a connection on $P\times E$, presumably the trivial connection $d$ if one starts with the zero endomorphism of $E$? Leibniz relation does not suffice. One could say let us make a convention here. 
But the more general question is how does one define $(F^*\nabla)_X$ when $X\in\ker{dF}$, in general?

Comment: What is $F^*s$?

Comment: I don't know how to define $F^*\nabla$ functorially (i.e., without using local co-ordinates and/or trivializations). I suggest first working this out using local co-ordinates and trivializations.

Comment: I take it back. Your equation is right. But I still recommend playing around with it using local co-ordinates and trivialization. It's a rather confusing equation (at least for me).

Comment: From the right-hand side of your equation, if $dF(X) = 0$ then $(F^*\nabla)_X = 0$ as well  (note it should be $dF$, not $df$).

Comment: I don't understand the statement "a connection on $E \to pt$ is an endomorphism of $E$''.  I would have thought it is a map $E \to E\otimes \Omega^1_{\pt},$ and since $\Omega^1_{\pt} = 0$, there is a unique connection, namely the zero map.  This makes sense in terms of parallel transport: over a point there is nowhere to transport anything!

Comment: I second Deane's suggestion to do it in local trivialization. Your equation does not actually directly define the pullback connection for all sections of the bundle $F^*E$. The expression only makes sense for pullbacks of sections $s$ of $E$ with $F$. So it should come as no surprise that if you plug-in $X$ such that $dF(X) = 0$, both sides evaluate to zero. What you then need to do is to use linearity of the connection plus the Leibniz rule, since starting with any local frame on $E$ you now already know how to parallel transport the frame. 

Comment: Emerton, you are right.

Comment: Over a pt, connections vanish (since vector fields & 1-forms are 0). In general "$dF(X)$" makes no sense as a vector field on $B$. View connections as additive maps from sections of $E$ to sections of $E \otimes \Omega^1_B$ over *varying opens* in $B$. Local sections of $F^{\ast}(E)$ are function-linear combinations of $F$-pullbacks of local sections of $E$, so the pullback rule (using pullback of 1-forms and of local sections) and Leibniz yield uniqueness. Construction with local coords gives local existence (& yields d when $B$ is pt and $E$ trivial), so by uniqueness get global existence. 

Comment: As an aside, it feels slightly circular (or ironic) to appeal to parallel transport intuition when creating this definition, since the very definition of parallel transport along general parametric curves $\gamma:J\rightarrow B$ (with an interval $J$ in $\mathbf{R}$ of positive length) -- whose image could be horribly "self-crossing" -- is to disentangle everything using the *pullback* connection $\gamma^{\ast}(\nabla)$ on the pullback bundle $\gamma^{\ast}(E)$ (with pullback metric). Over $J$ it unravels since bundles are globally trivial (via linear ODE's and a separate connection argument)

Comment: Please read the second answer below!

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this old question like me, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228111/pullback-connection and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155173/how-to-induce-a-connection-on-a-submanifold , where it is explained that affine connections can't be pulled back (but as stated below, e.g. in Milnor-Stasheff p.292 connections can be pulled back to the pullback bundle).

Answer (score 18):

Here's my summary of the situation:

1) First, observe that the space of local sections of the pullback bundle is generated by the space of sections of the original bundle composed with the map $F$. (This is better stated using sheaf language)

2) So, using the Leibniz rule, it suffices to define the pullback connection on a section obtained by composing a section of the original bundle with $F$.

3) The formula given above accomplishes this. It is worth noting that in this formula you should view $X$ as a single vector and *not* as a vector field.

Comment: As an aside, I stumbled onto this, because the use of a pullback connection is implicit when analyzing variations of geodesics and Jacobi fields on a Riemannian manifold. I've never seen this discussed explicitly in any textbook or paper, but it's actually quite necessary to make all the arguments rigorous.

Comment: Dear Deane: Aha, I didn't think of the interpretation with $X$ as a single vector (since the notation $\nabla_X$ is usually used with $X$ a vector field).  OK, that then makes sense, but working that pointwise then requires a separate argument to verify the smoothness aspect (i.e., recognizing how to bypass the single-vector formulation after all).  If we use the 1-form formulation then we work with local smooth sections throughout, so smoothness "comes along for the ride", and the single-vector interpretation can be inferred afterwards.  Well, six of one, half dozen of the other. :)

Comment: Dear BCnrd, could you clarify what smoothness aspect you are referring to?

Comment: Dear Deane: I just mean that if we make a pointwise construction then we may need to do more work (an explicit calculations over a suitable small open domain, or something else) to verify that its output is smooth in local coordinates, whereas if we make construction in terms of local sections of bundles (or in other words, from the viewpoint of sheaves) then the smoothness of the output of the connection operator drops out automatically from the framework. 

Comment: Dear BCnrd, thanks for the clarification. But I don't think there's any additional work required to verify smoothness. Smoothness of the pull-back connection follows directly from the smoothness of the original connection, smoothness of $F$, linear pointwise dependence on the tangent vector, and the Leibniz formula.

Comment: Dear Deane: You're right, it is the same content, just done in a different order. I tend to prefer postponing the "pointwise" aspect until the very end because in the algebraic (and especially scheme setting, with families over a base that may not be reduced) it is not something we can always use in the characterization step (it is just a "bonus" after the fact).

Comment: Wait, really? 1) just seems clearly false to me, especially if $F$ is not locally injective. Am I missing something?

Comment: @seub, indeed it looks funny. I suggest writing it all out in local coordinates assuming $F$ is a local immersion and observing that it all still works if $F$ is not

Comment: @DeaneYang ah, I thought so. Maybe it's worth editing the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @seub, to be honest, I'm not sure what you'd like me to add. Could you write a comment with whatever you'd like to see and I'll insert it into the answer (and crediting you).

Comment: @DeaneYang: I'm afraid I don't have a good suggestion because I don't understand very well myself what's the right approach to define this pullback connection, I wish I did. Your answer seems like the write approach superficially, but the whole answer relies on 1) being true, which is not the case. That's a problem! If you think the right way to justify it is to write everything in coordinates, that's fine, but it's just a different answer. That's just my humble opinion.

Comment: @DeaneYang: by the way, in 1), not only existence is not always true, but neither uniqueness I think when f is not locally surjective, which is another problem for the well-definedness of the pullback connection. Also I'm not sure what is gained by writing "generated by". Maybe the whole idea is just no good!

Comment: @seub, The pullback of a bundle $E$ by a smooth map $F: P \rightarrow B$ is defined as follows: The fiber over each $x \in P$ is $E_{F(x)}$ and the set of all smooth sections consists of the all smooth maps $s: P \rightarrow B$ such that $s(x) \in E_{F(x)}$. It is straightforward to show that if $T: O\times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow E$ is a local trivialization of $E$, then $S: F^{-1}(O)\times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow E$, where $S(x,v) = T(F(x),v)$ is a local trivialization of $F^*E$. After that, it is straightforward to define the pullback connection using the local trivialization.

Comment: I  do not think that the space of  pull back  sections generate even locally the space of sections in the initial space $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=x^2$ pull back sections areeven function(assuming we have trivial line bundle). Could you please ellaborate your answer in particular point 1)? Thank you.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I think that "generate" is read with coefficients in the ring of smooth functions over the domain, not just with coefficients being the reals. (May be simpler to reduce your question more and look first at the case where you have $f(x) = 0$. The pullback sections are only the constant sections.)

Comment: @WillieWong  yes I see thank you.

Comment: @WillieWong  For  parallelizable riemannian manifold $M$ there is no any ambiguity  of speaking about $TM$ and $f^* TM$. In this  condition is the  space of all diffeomorphisms preserving LC  connections the same as the isometric group?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: not in general. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$ where $A$ is any invertible $n\times n$ matrix is a diffeomorphism. Unless $A\in O(n)$ the mapping is in general not an isometry. But as an affine mapping the connection is preserved. This notion of affine mappings generalize to arbitrary Riemannian manifolds (in fact, to arbitrary manifolds with affine connections). In general, the affine group is bigger than the isometry group. But there are times when the two can be identified. ...

Comment: ... for example, a theorem of [Yano](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969418?seq=1) (final theorem of the paper) states that on a compact orientable Riemannian manifold, any _infinitesimal_ affine transformation is necessarily an _infinitesimal_ isometry. (Or that restricted to the connected component of the identity, the affine group is the same as the isometry group; this restriction to the connected component is necessary, as you can take two spheres of unequal sizes as your manifold, and make your map swap their metrics.)

Comment: i like the approach of viewing X as a single vector. but the rhs has to lose the F*.

Comment: @peter, without the $F^*$, the right side is an element in the bundle $E$, but the left side is an element in the bundle $F^*E$. You could also write the right side as $(\nabla_{F_*X}s)\circ F$.

Comment: but if i view X as a single vector, i will get out a single element, what does composition mean for that?

Comment: @DeaneYang I somehow agree with your argument. One thing that is not clear enough (at least to me) is the well-definedness of (2), since a section of the pull-back bundle may admit different linear combinations. I believe we should prove that if $F^*(s)(x_0) = 0$ then $F^*\nabla(F^*s)(x_0)$ should also be zero. However I cannot prove this...

Comment: @Sherose, it suffices to show that given two different frames of the pullback bundle, the transition matrix is a smooth function of the domain. This follows from the fact that the transition matrix is a smooth function of the range.

Answer (score 9):

Just to put what others have said into an explicit formula, note that any section of $F^*E$ is of the form

$\sum_j \varphi_j F^*s_j$,

for certain $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n \in C^{\infty}(P)$, and $s_1, \ldots, s_n \in \Gamma^{\infty}(E)$. Then in the notation of the question (with $X \in T_pP$ a single tangent vector), at $p \in P$ we have by the Leibniz rule and the defining relation of $F^*\nabla$,

$(F^*\nabla)_X \left(\sum_j \varphi_j F^*s_j\right) = \sum_j \left( d\varphi_j(X)   F^*s_j  + \varphi_j (F^*\nabla)_X F^*s_j \right) 
= \sum_j \left( d\varphi_j(X) F^*s_j + \varphi_j F^*(\nabla_{dF(X)}s_j) \right) 
$

(with everything evaluated at $p$ where appropriate). This gives back $F^*\nabla = d$ in your example where $B$ is a point and you take the zero endomorphism of $E$.

Comment: Can you prove your first claim? It sounds just false to me. For example, take $F : [0,1] \to B$ a curve with a self-intersection.

Comment: say $F(t_0)=F(t_1)$ is the self-intersection, then let  $\varphi_j(t_j)=1$ and $\varphi_j(t_{1-j})=0$ and $\varphi_0+\varphi_1=1$. then in the supports of these coefficients the curve is injective.

Comment: @seub as another counter example $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=x^2$ pull back sections are just even functions.

Comment: If we define by this, then well-definedness problem comes out: for any section, it may admit different linear combinations. So how to prove the definition is independent of choice?

Answer (score 6):

Hi, I have seen the equation you gave as a definition many times. For example, I think it is also used in a corresponding Wikipedia article. Nevertheless, as you correctly pointed out, it does not give a reasonable/unique description. A better formulation/definition of the pullback connection can be found for example in Milnor's and Stasheff's book 'Characteristic classes' on p. 292, Lemma 3 and its proof (definition by universal property/commutative diagram; proof: computation in local coordinates; it's the precise version of what the equation you gave tries to capture). I hope this helps more or less.

Comment: The commutative diagram in Milnor and Stasheff is exactly the same equation, only written in a different language. As others pointed out, it does define the pull-back connection uniquely but you can not use it directly for arbitrary sections of the pull-back bundle.


Answer (score 5):

See 19.12.6 (page 250) in this [book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

To Matt:
The relation $(F^*\nabla)_X=0$ does not satisfy Leibniz relation. 
Meanwhile I found out the answer to my question (a friend clarified it for me).

It turns out that there is an isomorphism $\Gamma(P;\pi^*E)\simeq \Gamma(P;\mathbb{C})\otimes \Gamma(B;E)$ where the tensor product is over $\Gamma(B;\mathbb{C})$.  It is obviously true when $E$ is a vector space. Now use Leibniz relation
$\nabla_X(f\otimes s)=X(f)\otimes s+f\otimes\nabla_Xs$
to extend the connection from $\Gamma(B;E)$ to $\Gamma (P;\pi^*E)$.
In the trivial case one gets indeed that $\nabla_X(f\otimes s)=X(f)\otimes s$.

Comment: @Unknown: see my comment above. The equation you wrote down is only meaningful for pull-backs of sections $s$. If you multiply $F^*s$ by an arbitrary function $h$, it will no longer be the pull back of a section over $B$ if $h$ is not constant along $F^{-1}B$. In other words, you were trying to force Leibniz rule somewhere it has no business being. The given expression is, indeed, enough to specify the pull-back connection, but it is not so simple as plug-and-play. 

Comment: Willie i didn't say it was easy:) In the background lurks the isomorphism

$\Gamma(P;\pi^*E)\simeq \Gamma(P;\mathbb{C})\otimes \Gamma(B;E)$ which is by not obvious(at least not to me).
But Leibniz relation does make sense and it does define the connection everywhere and it also explains the trivial connection on the trivial bundle.


Comment: Dear unknown: the isom. you're using is false in complex-analytic and algebraic cases (unsure in $C^\infty$-case, but seems silly to use a defn that only works there when there's a simple procedure applicable in all cases). Think more locally (it's good for you!): use local existence and global uniqueness to get global existence. What you propose with "global" tensors works locally with no hard work; then use uniqueness to globalize. Your comment to Matt is unclear since your original statement of the pullback-relation with global vector fields makes no sense ($dF(X)$ makes no sense on $B$).

Comment: 
Dear BCnrd,
Thank you for your interesting comments but...
1) I was only interested in the differentiable case. I am not sure what you mean by a connection in the analytic or algebraic cases. (an analytic(algebraic) splitting of the tangent bundle?) so I am really satisfied with the isomorphism of smooth sections i was talking about. By the way, it's not mine.  
2)I admit the comment to Matt lacked details, probably thinking that it was clear  $X$ should be thought as a tangent vector and not a vector field (as I wrote); (retrospectively that was really not the main issue of the question); 



Comment: Dear unknown: later in life you'll want to use complex manifolds or complex algebraic varieties. (Connections remain all about making vector fields act as "directional deriv." operators on sections of the bundle, as in diff'ble case.) Then no bump functions, so cannot work entirely so "globally" as above. That's why I outlined an alternative to exploit your preferred calculations on a local level, coupled with global uniqueness (which can be proved by local calculations!) to infer global existence. It really is easier that way (e.g., no non-obvious isoms needed). You'll appreciate it later.

Comment: @user11538: I don't think this answer is correct: in order for that tensor product to make sense, how can $\Gamma(P, \mathbb C)$ be a module over $\Gamma(B, \mathbb C)$? In other words, how can you multiply a function on $P$ by a function on $B$ and obtain a function on $P$?

Answer (score 1):

OP's example is not correct for a point already.

First thing, connection is a differential operator $\nabla: \Gamma(E) \otimes TX \rightarrow \Gamma (E)$ of first order with a symbol $\partial$.

This amounts to saying that it satisfies Leibniz rule in the following sense:

$\nabla_{v} (f \gamma) = f\nabla_v(\gamma) + \partial_v (f) \gamma$

For a point, there is no need to even check Leibniz rule, because $TX = 0$, so there is no place from where you could obtain an automorphism! Connection allows you to derive the sections *along a vector field*, and every vector field on a point is $0$.

Moreover, pullback of the connection (which is defined correctly by the formula in the post) is a trivial connection on a trivial bundle (and it is canonical, because all fibers are canonically identified).